# How to create a table in Hive with a column of data type MAP(VARCHAR,ARRAY[MAP(VARCHAR,VARCHAR)]

Tags: arrays, types, hive, maps, hiveql

I am trying to create a table which has a complex data type. And the data types are listed below.

`map<string, array <map <String,String>>>` , the data I am looking is as follows

```
 {'tags': [{'type': 'type1', 'value': 'value1'}, {'type': 'type1', 'value': 'value1'}]}
```

Kindly help me with create table in Hive as well as inserting values to this Hive table.